# Trying to get API flight info displayed

Tags: php, html, json, curl

Amsterdam Airport Schiphol provides access to their flight info API for free. I am trying to build a simple website where I can make the info visible for myself.

I have build websites with html/php/mysql over 10 years ago but I am completely lost in this new world of json/curl/APIs. If someone can give me a kickstart or example that I can build off that would be great.

There is an example of how to use the API on the API website but it doesn't show anything at all (code attached).

Review code for errors, none found.

API website: https://developer.schiphol.nl/apis/flight-api/v4/flights?version=latest

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Public flight</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <?php
echo '<h1>Public flight API</h1>';
$app_id  = '7c1af90e';
$app_key = '35f61a4f0b2cacce9bc0d502ad56ce35';

$curl = curl_init('https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'resourceversion: v4',
    'app_id: ' . $app_id,
    'app_key: ' . $app_key
  ),
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl)) {
  echo 'Error - ' . curl_error($curl);
} else {
  $array = json_decode($response, true);
  echo '<table>';
  foreach ($array['flights'] as $flight) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $flight['flightName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . (string) $flight['scheduleDate'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
curl_close($curl);
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expect to see flight info but nothing is displayed. HTML tables are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'resourceversion: v4',
    'app_id: ' . $app_id,
    'app_key: ' . $app_key,
    'accept: application/json'
),
```

In your header you must accept application/json. Then you will retrieve results.  Tested your code locally after my fix and the html page is generated fine.

Result output is:

```
Public flight API
HV5588  2019-07-16
SU2193  2019-07-16
KL3183  2019-07-16
AM7035  2019-07-16
HV6730  2019-07-16
KL2688  2019-07-16
HV5624  2019-07-16
KL2676  2019-07-16
HV5752  2019-07-16
KL2624  2019-07-16
HV5662  2019-07-16
KL2690  2019-07-16
HV6874  2019-07-16
KL2620  2019-07-16
HV5428  2019-07-16
KL2581  2019-07-16
HV6674  2019-07-16
KL2630  2019-07-16
HV5542  2019-07-16
HV6146  2019-07-16
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Do you have any info on how I can filter my request? for instance I would only like to see results that contain PHAO in the aircraft registration part.

Comment: That's a think that should be supported by the API of schiphol. You could have a look in their documentation. If they don't have something like this implemented in their API and they only return all the results then you have to filter yourself using php.